# What is known about the set $S$ of couples of rationals $(q,q')$ such that $\zeta(q+iq')$ is rational?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

The question is the title. For example, if we could show that $S$ is finite, then this would entail that every large enough integer $n$ is such that $\zeta(2n+1)$ is irrational and that, under RH, almost all non-trivial zeros of $\zeta$ have irrational imaginary part. Has this question been studied? Any reference?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This includes all trivial zeros so it is infinite.

Comment: Is there another example except nonpositive integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This set includes the non-positive integers (including the trivial zeros)
so the set is infinite.

I would be interested in another example.

Answer (score 2):

See D. Maser's [Rational Values of the Riemann zeta function](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X11001235). In it he proves that the number of rational numbers $s\in[2,3]$ with denominator at most $D$ such that $\zeta(s)$ is also a rational with denominator at most $D$ is $O\left( \left(\frac{\log(D)}{\log\log(D)}\right)^2 \right)$.

Of course the set is probably empty.

Comment: Is there a nontrivial solution known?

Comment: @joro, not as far as I know.